# Debugging optimization of a function

Tags: r, function, optimization

I have a function that works just fine when asked to calculate the -logLik given parameters. However, if I try to optimize the function it returns an error message. I'm familiar with `debug()` to work through problems with a function, but how would I go about debugging optimization for a function that othwerwise works?

```
Lik <- function(params, data) { 
....
return(-log( **likelihood equation** ))
}
```

These work!

```
Lik(params=c(3,10,2,9,rowMeans(data[1,])[1]), data = data1)
Lik(params=c(3,10,2,9.5,rowMeans(data[1,])[1]), data = data1)
```

> > GENE1 32.60705
> >
> > GENE1 32.31657

This doesn't work!

```
optim(params=c(3,10,2,9,rowMeans(data[1,])[1]), data = data1, Lik, method = "BFGS")
```

> Error in optim(params = c(3, 10, 2, 9, rowMeans(data[1, ])[1]), data = data1, : 
>    cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

Comment: Look at  `?optim` for how the function should be defined.

Comment: Further options will be passed to the function, so having data as an argument is fine. The problem is that the `optim` parameter name for the parameters to optimize over is `par`, not `params`. You don't need to change your `Lik` function, it just needs to have the parameters to optimize over as the first argument, the name doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `optim` parameter name for the parameters to optimize over is `par`, not `params`. You don't need to change your `Lik` function, it just needs to have the parameters to optimize over as the first argument, the name doesn't matter.

This should work. Here I name the `fn` argument too, but because the others are named the positional finding works.

```
optim(par=c(3, 10, 2, 9, rowMeans(data[1, ])[1]), 
      data=data1, fn=Lik, method="BFGS")
```

So what was happening in your code was that it was saving both `params` and `data` to send to the function, and then the first unnamed parameter was `Lik` so it was getting matched to the first parameter of `optim`, which is `par`, the parameters to optimize over. That parameter should be a numeric (a double, technically) but you were sending it a function (a closure, technically), hence the error message.

To debug, you could have turned on debugging for optim `debug(optim)` and then at the first browse, explored what the parameters were that it was using. You would have found exactly this, though simply in exploring the parameters, you would have discovered you named them incorrectly.

```
Browse[2]> print(par)
function(params, data) {... return(-log( **likelihood equation** ))}
Browse[2]> print(fn)
Error in print(fn) : argument "fn" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to use built-in function names as object names created (or to be created) by the user.

When there is no "data" object (a matrix or a data frame) yet created by the user, R interpreter scans the environments and finds that the only object named "data" is the built in "data" function:

```
> class(data)
[1] "function"
> str(data)
function (..., list = character(), package = NULL, lib.loc = NULL, verbose = getOption("verbose"), 
    envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Hence R treats the "data" object as a closure (a function declaration) that cannot be subsetted:

```
> data[1]
Error in data[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

So you should change the name of the parameter to sth other than data.

And a second point, the syntax of optim is:

```
optim(par, fn, gr = NULL, ...,
           method = c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN",
                      "Brent"),
           lower = -Inf, upper = Inf,
           control = list(), hessian = FALSE)
```

So in your example, the second parameter supplied to optim should be the function Lik, not the data. And the interpreter tries to interpret data1 as a closure. You can try to swap the positions of data1 and Lik.

And more importantly as @李哲源ZheyuanLi also points, there is no parameter in optim named as "data". You should just write it as "data1" in place of the additional function parameters "...".

And last, as also @Aaron pointed out, the first parameter is named "par" not params".

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi True, another problem is the order of parameters of optim. data = data1 and Lik are misplaced. And of course there is no parameter for optim named as "data" as you also pointed out.

Comment: Naming the parameter `data` is not the problem in the code. And while I usually agree that naming something `data` is a bad idea, but using it as a parameter in a function is another matter. It's commonly done (as in `lm`, for example) and can make sense in the kind of functions you'd want to optimize over.